# Some issues with Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to parse .xlsx file through Laravel Excel library.

[Library](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs)

I've made this code in my Controller just for check.

```
    $file = $this->argument('filepath');

    $excelCollectionExcel = Excel::load($file, function($reader) {
        })->get()->toArray();

    dd($excelCollectionExcel);
```

And now response time is close to 2 minutes(In my Excel file are only 2000 rows) and I think it's not good.When I save this file to .csv and make request, I get reponse for 10 seconds. How can I change that? (I've enabled ignoreEmptyRows in my excel config file and few times made config:clear)

Comment: Can you use a `csv` instead? XLSX are known for being crappy when parsing from a performance perspective

Comment: Hi! I think it's really bad way to parse .xlsx to csv and back csv to xlsx